# Bouncy Castle c# : Find public-key Fingerprint in PgP Message, possible?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pgp

I'm trying to figure out the message from a PgP public key, ie so I know with what I private key can decrypt the message.

> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
>
> Version: BCPG C# v1.7.4114.6375
>
> ....
>
> -----END PGP MESSAGE-----

But I found the solutions were for the Java version. See: http://heli0s.darktech.org/?p=433
The C# version don't have "PGPPublicKeyRingCollection". Maybe someone has a tip for me? Or is the only way to work with try and catch?

Dany